# update listview from an Array adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

I'm trying to refresh the list view when I click on a single item of the list view.
For example I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public class RssItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
private TextView txtTitle;
private ImageView imgFavourite;
private int resourceId;
private Context context;
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

public RssItemsAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<Item> items)
{
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Item getItem(int index) {
    return items.get(index);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    Item item = getItem(position);      

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);
    }

    txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
    txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());

    imgFavourite = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.favourite);
    imgFavourite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (item.isFavourite() == true) {
                imgFavourite.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off);
            }
            else {
                imgFavourite.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
            }
        }
    });

    // add a "star" icon on favourite items
    if (item.isFavourite() == true)
        imgFavourite.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
    else
        imgFavourite.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off);


    return row;
}
```

Every time I click on the `imgFavourite` icon it should change. Where is the problem?

Comment: use notifyDateSetChange() method of listView

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are ever changing the value of item.isFavourite(). Assuming you want to toggle when that item is clicked...

```
imgFavourite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Toggle the current state
        item.setIsFavourite(!item.isFavourite());

        if (item.isFavourite() == true) {
            imgFavourite.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_off);
        }
        else {
            imgFavourite.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
        }
    }
});
```

Also, you should be doing this kind of work in the ListView's onItemClickListsner. As is, this will create a new onClickListener each time a new row is brought into view. Beyond that, check into the "view holder pattern".

Comment: How can I do this work in the ListView's onItemClickListener?? I mean how can I access to the listView childs??

Comment: You are given the item position in that callback, then you can use it to call ListView.getItemAtPosition(position). You are also given the View that was clicked if you need to manipulate it.

I now realize that you probably only want the imgFavourite to be clickable. If that is the case, then forget what I said about onItemClicked(...) since that will apply to the entire row.